# Proof of Variable Selection Consistency for LASSO in Zhao & Yu, 2006

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, lasso, consistency

I'm going through the proof of Proposition 1 in Zhao & Yu, 2006 (https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume7/zhao06a/zhao06a.pdf), titled *On Model Selection Consistency of LASSO*. The proof is in Appendix A. Here they claim that, if a solution $\widehat u^n$ exists and the following hold:

$$C_{11}^n (\sqrt{n}\widehat{u}^n(1)) - W^n(1) = -\frac{-\lambda_n}{2\sqrt(n)}sign(\beta^n_{(1)}), \tag{1}$$
$$|\widehat u^n(1)| < |\beta^n_{(1)}|, \tag{2}$$
$$\frac{-\lambda_n}{2\sqrt{n}}\mathbf{1} \le C^n_{21}(\sqrt{n}\widehat u^n(1)) - W^n(2) \le \frac{\lambda_n}{2\sqrt{n}}\mathbf{1} \tag{3}$$

then $sign(\widehat\beta^n_{(1)}) = sign(\beta^n_{(1)})$ and $\widehat\beta^n_{(2)} = 0$.

I understand this part. The next step, which I do not understand, is to show that such a solution $\widehat u^n$ exists. They claim this is implied by

$$|(C_{11}^n)^{-1}W^n(1)| < \sqrt{n}|\beta^n_{(1)}| - \frac{\lambda_n}{2n}|(C_{11}^n)^{-1}sign(\beta^n_{(1)})| \tag{4}$$

Can someone explain how this guarantees the existence of a solution $\widehat u^n$ which satisfies (1) and (2)?